# Present Continuous with 'need'

Tags: present-continuous

Wood Chickens "Skunk Ape" 7"

> First things first - really did love the Dead Milkmen during my formative High School years. The title track on this rubs that Milkmen vibe, pretty damn close. As for the other two tracks, they rollick through the hillbilly fields, skipping about like Mojo Nixon on a harder hooch. Not really anything **I'm needing** to hear again

Why  present continuous here,is it to emphasize the idea (it is really something I don't need right now)

Answer (score 1):

The present continuous expresses things that are happening "right now" or "in the moment."

> I need a bath.

Generally speaking, I am dirty and probably feel it.

> I am needing a bath right about now.

At this moment in time, right now, I need a bath. Perhaps I just played in mud or fell in a sewer drain.

Answer (score 0):

It's used with progressive to refer tentatively to a present wish or attitude.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please include the **research** you have done to arrive at this answer. This ensures the credibility of your answer and further demonstrates your point.